# SQLException - Transaction BEGIN / COMMIT mismatch

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, transactions, sqlexception

Have you encountered this exception for a stored procedure which does indeed have a balanced transaction block?

I double-checked the stored procedure and it has exactly one `TRANSACTION BEGIN` and cooresponding `TRANSACTION END`

**Error logged**

```
SqlException - Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.  The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. - Delete failed - stack:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)     at System.Data.SqlClient.S ... [Rest of stack trace truncated by logging system]`
```

**Additional Info**

The stored procedure does contain `EXEC` calls to another stored procedure.  Would a mismatched transaction pair here cause the error to be surfaced in this way?

**Update**
It turns out that there was a violation of a foreign key constraint within the nested stored procedure.  The outer transaction did not include a Try/Catch block and had `SET XACT_ABORT ON` specified, which did not properly handle either a commit or rollback.  Also added a check for @@TransactionCount > 0 before attempting a rollback

Comment: The foreign key constraint was a huge help for me here! I ran into a similar problem with sqlalchemy from python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it would. Each BEGIN increments [`@@trancount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx), each commit decrements it. Only when the count gets to 0 is the transaction really committed. Your procedure, as a caller, cannot control this. It is the job of the called procedures to behave properly and balance the BEGIN and COMMIT count, if any of the called procedures has a imbalance, you'll see this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930156/transaction-count-after-execute-indicates-a-mismatching-number-of-begin-and-comm I have posted here

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure you don't have path that produces this

```
BEGIN TRAN

ROLLBACK TRAN

COMMIT TRAN
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're going down the right path. If a nested procedure call creates transactions, they affect the calling procedure.

Check that other procedure

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have inadvertently written

```
 return
 commit
```

in place of

```
 commit
 return
```

For me, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of PROCEDURE creation text

**SET XACT_ABORT ON;**

It will ensure that if nothing got executed, the transaction is aborted entirely.

MSDN Doc: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792(v=sql.105).aspx