# Rollback transaction from called stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2014

I have a simple scenario: logger procedure and main procedure from which logger is called. I am trying to rollback transaction inside logger which is started in main, but getting errors. I am not sure why. Here are the two procs and the error message I receive:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spLogger
AS
BEGIN
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
       PRINT @@TRANCOUNT
       ROLLBACK
    END
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spCaller
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
       BEGIN TRANSACTION
          RAISERROR('', 16, 1)
       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       EXEC spLogger
    END CATCH
END
GO

EXEC spCaller
```

> 1 Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure spLogger, Line 15 Transaction
>   count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT
>   statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The error message is clear: number of active TXs at the end of SP should be the same as number of active TXs at the beginning.

So, when at execution of `dbo.spLogger` begins the number of active TXs (`@@TRANCOUNT`) is `1` if we execute within this SP the `ROLLBACK` statement this'll cancel **ALL** active TXs and `@@TRANCOUNT` becomes `0` -> `error/exception`

2) If you want just to avoid writing `IF @@TRANCOUNT ... ROLLBACK` within every `CATCH` block of every user SP then don't it. I would call `dbo.spLogger` within `CATCH` block after `ROLLBACK`.

3) If I have to call SPs from other SP using TXs then I would use following template (source: [Rusanu's blog](http://rusanu.com/2010/11/22/try-catch-throw-exception-handling-in-t-sql/))

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER()
                                   , @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
                                   , @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        throw;
    end catch   
end
```

with few small changes:

a) `SET XACT_ABORT ON`

b) I would call `dbo.spLogger` within `CATCH` block only when there is `@@TRANCOUNT = 0`:

```
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.spLogger ... params ...
END
THROW -- or RAISERROR(@message, 16, @xstate)
```

Why ? Because if `dbo.spLogger` SP will insert rows into a `dbo.DbException` table when one TX is active then in case of `ROLLBACK` SQL Server will have to `ROLLBACL` also these rows.

Example:

```
SP1 -call-> SP2 -call-> SP3
                         |err/ex -> CATCH & RAISERROR (no full ROLLBACK)
              <-----------
              |err/ex -> CATCH & RAISERROR (no full ROLLBACK)
 <-------------
|err/ex -> CATCH & FULL ROLLBACK & spLogger
```

4) **Update**

```
CREATE PROC TestTx
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN -- B
    ROLLBACK -- C
END 
-- D
GO

-- Test
BEGIN TRAN -- A - @@TRANCOUNT = 1
EXEC dbo.TestTx 
    /*
    Number of active TXs (@@TRANCOUNT) at the begining of SP is 1
    B - @@TRANCOUNT = 2
    C - @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    D - Execution of SP ends. SQL Server checks & generate an err/ex
        Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
    */
COMMIT -- E - Because @@TRANCOUNT is 0 this statement generates
```

another err/ex The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
    -- End of Test

5) See [autonomous transactions: it requires SQL2008+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/08/22/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008/).

> An Autonomous transaction is essentially a nested transaction where
>   the inner transaction is not affected by the state of the outer
>   transaction. In other words, you can leave the context of current
>   transaction (outer transaction) and call another transaction
>   (autonomous transaction). Once you finish work in the autonomous
>   transaction, you can come back to continue on within current
>   transaction. What is done in the autonomous transaction is truly DONE
>   and won’t be changed no matter what happens to the outer transaction.

Comment: Could you please clarify this statement more "The error message is clear: number of active TXs at the end of SP should be the same as number of active TXs at the beginning."

Comment: Hello, sure it works when I do rollback before calling logger. I suspect this is a limitation I can not workaround...

Comment: @TheGameiswar, I think it is 

`--trancount here
EXEC dbo.spLogger
--and here should be the same`

Comment: @Bogdan, I think I will end up with creating a CLR logger procedure that will open a new connection and log which will log in any case because it will not be in the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

keeping aside all xact_abort stuff,i see no reason why you should get the error.So did some research and here are the observations

----This works

```
alter PROCEDURE spCaller
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
       BEGIN TRANSACTION
          RAISERROR('', 16, 1)
       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
     rollback 

    END CATCH
END
GO
```

---Again this works,took the text of sp and kept it in catch block

```
alter PROCEDURE spCaller
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
       BEGIN TRANSACTION
          RAISERROR('', 16, 1)
       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
     --rollback 
     IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
       PRINT @@TRANCOUNT
       ROLLBACK
    END
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

After some research Found answer by [Remus Rusanu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930156/transaction-count-after-execute-indicates-a-mismatching-number-of-begin-and-comm) here:

If your caller starts a transaction and the calee hits, say, a deadlock (which aborted the transaction), how is the callee going to communicate to the caller that the transaction was aborted and it should not continue with 'business as usual'? The only feasible way is to re-raise an exception, forcing the caller to handle the situation. **If you silently swallow an aborted transaction and the caller continues assuming is still in the original transaction, only mayhem can ensure (and the error you get is the way the engine tries to protect itself).**

In your case,you are getting the error only when using a stored proc  and  trying to raise the error ,since a stored proc starts a seperate data context.The error you are getting may be SQL way of telling that this wont work.