# Transaction count exception after EXECUTE

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to save log details to a table in SQL. I want to catch both success and errors during SQL operations. Even when there is an SQL exception occured, I want to feed that as well.

I have set up an output parameter, and depending on whether it's success or error, its value changes. While calling this SP I'm getting an error like

> *Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1. A transaction that was started in a MARS batch is still active at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back*

Below is the complete SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_PIP_Employee]
    @Flag int,
    @Empid int,
    @Name varchar(500),
    @Designation varchar(200),
    @Department varchar(200),
    @DateofJoin datetime,
    @Phone varchar(10),
    @Isactive int,
    @LoginUser nvarchar(500),
    @ReturnId int output

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON ;
     DECLARE @errorMessage VarChar(8000), 
                @errorSeverity Int,
                @errorState Int,
                @AlCode varchar(50),
                @AlDesc varchar(1000),
                @AlOp varchar(50),
                @AlStatus varchar(50)
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        IF (@Flag = 1)
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PIP_Employee 
                       GROUP BY Name, Phone 
                       HAVING COUNT(ID) > 0 
                          AND Name = @Name AND Phone = @Phone)
            BEGIN
                SET @ReturnId = 0
                SET @AlCode = 'ERR_1001'
                SET @AlDesc = CONCAT('Add Record of ',@Name,' failed due to duplicate entry')
                SET @AlOp = 'ADD'
                SET @AlStatus = 'ERROR'
                GOTO AuditLog
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.PIP_Employee (Name, Designation, Department, DateofJoin, Phone, IsPresent) 
                VALUES (@Name, @Designation, @Department, @DateofJoin, @Phone, @Isactive)

                SET @ReturnId = 1
                  SET @AlCode = 'SUCC_1002'
                SET @AlDesc = CONCAT('Record of ',@Name,' added Successfully')
                SET @AlOp = 'ADD'
                SET @AlStatus = 'SUCCESS'
                GOTO AuditLog

            END

            return @ReturnId
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @ReturnId = 0
        SET @AlCode = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        SET @AlDesc = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @AlOp = 'SQL TRANSACTION FAILURE'
        SET @AlStatus = ERROR_STATE();

        IF (@@trancount > 0)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

            GOTO AuditLog 
            RETURN @ReturnId 

    END CATCH

    AuditLog:
    INSERT INTO dbo.PIP_AuditLog (Aud_Code, Aud_Desc, Aud_Operation, Aud_Status, Aud_Createddate, Aud_ActionBy) 
    VALUES (@AlCode, @AlDesc, @AlOp, @AlStatus, GETDATE(), @LoginUser)


    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

Comment: Can you try adding commit transaction after the insert statement in AuditLog. May be when the control comes to this section, the previous transaction is open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930156/transaction-count-after-execute-indicates-a-mismatching-number-of-begin-and-comm)

Comment: issue solved after adding commit transact after insert statement in auditlog. thank you prateek.